# How to choose Health check Path for Azure Functrions?

Tags: azure-functions

I have first Azure Function with HTTP Trigger. It is called few times day.
I would like to monitor its health.

I wonder what is right path for health check.
I wish not to trigger actual function every ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the diagnostic tools feature given by azure for the function app to check the availability & performance of your app.

[Diagnose and Solve Problem for Azure function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piy8d.png)

Comment: My goal is to create Alert. I assume that I would need path for Azure Function. Health Check. However I don't know what is correct path.

Comment: Can you help me understand , 
Do you need Path for Azure Function App(e.g. https://abc-func-xyz.azurewebsites.net) or you want to get notified if something is wrong or function is app is down ?

Comment: I would like create alert if Function is not responding correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check